# What's the easiest way to send texts from Django?

Tags: django, sms

I'm trying to create an app that will be able to text message user's phones. I'll be sending out only about 500 texts total, so I don't want to sign up for a paid service like Twilio. I google'd around for a bit, and all of the solutions date back to 2008, so I'm wondering if there's a newer and easier way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Having looked into it recently, I'm fairly certain you absolutely must pay for any and every SMS service (even Google Voice) in this instance. Once you've decided on a service there is probably a way to interface with it generically in python and therefore also django.